# *SOLVED* How do I sort columns in a Matrix view?

Tags: matrix, powerbi, calendar, dax, powerbi-desktop

I am attempting to create a gantt chart in Power Bi using the matrix view, and the end user wants it to have year, quarter, and month. The year and quarter columns are fine, but the month columns are out of order, and I cannot seem to figure out how to put them in order. My calendar table and everything in it are created using dax.

So far, I haven't really tried anything. I am assuming Power Bi is not recognizing them as months in a date table and that is why it is not sorting them accordingly, but alphabetically by quarter and year.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

You will need a column in your Date table that has month numbers, 1 - 12. Then you can select the Month Name from your Data table on the right and you'll see a tab called "Column Tools" pop up on the header. Click that and then click "Sort by column" and select the Month Number and confirm it's ascending.

This should do the trick.